# endiannes issues with c style strings

Tags: c, endianness

I was reading some tutorial on endianness. Got the integer part. But
the tutorial left of by mentioning whether endianness issues apply also
for C style strings, without mentioning correct answer.
Does endiannes apply to C style strings?
From my understanding, No. am I correct?

e.g., if I have string "cap" stored like this

```
char:    c    a    p   \0
addr: 1000 1001 1002 1003
```

Say it is written to file. When someone from a different endiannes reads it, I think it should still be ok, isn't it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Endianness only applies to entities which are longer than one byte. Thus, **narrow** C strings which are arrays of `char` should be OK.

If you have wide strings, however, of type `wchar_t[]`, then you should definitely be concerned about correctly handling endianness.